# How to Access Custom JS Object from $.getJSON() call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JS object that look something like this.

```
function Product() {
    this.prop1 = 1;
    this.prop2 = 2;
}

function Work(values) {
    this.prodID = 0;
    this.anotherProp = 1;

    this.updateProductID = function(newProdID) {
        var sourceURL = "the URL here";
        alert("ID is: " + this.product.prodID); //displays 0
        $.getJSON(sourceURL, function(data) {

            //I want to update the property like this
            this.product.prodID = data.Products.ProductID;
        })
    };
```

What I am trying to do is make a json call and populate the product.ProdID property of the instance of the Work Object but I always get this.product is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are within an `anonymous function`, your context changes. It's very common to `cache` a reference of your context which you can access via closure:

```
function Work(values) {
    var self = this;
    self.prodID = 0;
    self.anotherProp = 1;

    self.updateProductID = function(newProdID) {
        var sourceURL = "the URL here";
        alert("ID is: " + self.product.prodID); //displays 0
        $.getJSON(sourceURL, function(data) {

            //I want to update the property like this
            self.product.prodID = data.Products.ProductID;
        });
    };
}
```

Another way, which could be to `proxy` the context via jQuerys `$.proxy()` method.

```
this.updateProductID = $.proxy(function(newProdID) {
    // this is now pointing to the "outer" this
}, this);
```

That is accomplished by using Javascripts `.call()` / `.apply()` method, which overwrites the `this` for a called function.

Answer (score 0):

`this` changes inside enclosures.  You should store `this` first like so:

```
var upper_this = this;
this.updateProductID = function(newProdID) {
    var sourceURL = "the URL here";
    alert("ID is: " + this.product.prodID); //displays 0
    $.getJSON(sourceURL, function(data) {

        //I want to update the property like this
        upper_this.prodID = data.Products.ProductID;
    })
};
```